# app icon replaced blackberry

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Having some app icon with a Blackberry application built using Phonegap. When it installs I can see the application icon on the device. However after using the app a couple of times the icon is replaced by a generic folder icon. 
I have the icon in a folder inside the root folder like - appfolder/images/icon.png.

When I go to setup to manage the applications the application icon is visible and shows up alongside the app. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** Happens when the app crashes due to low memory...

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml and make sure you have the following line in it:

```
<icon src="images/icon.png" width="72" height="72" />
```

Point it to the image you'd like to be your icon. You can even specify the width and height depending on the resolution.

Comment: I do have the line in there. It happens if the app crashes due to low memory. The app does a lot of base64 encoding and sometimes is force closed due to low memory. At that point the icon disappears and is replaced by a generic folder icon.

Comment: More a suggestion than a fix, but I'd want to prevent it from crashing if you can as it sounds like this is a common thing. Preventing it from crashing will in turn fix the icon issue.

Comment: Its not an app crash...Its a memory warning similar to whats discussed here - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441/highlight/true...Trying to see if the new webworks SDK fixes the missing icon issue.